# Improvements on my icing

Tags: texturing

I'm new to Blender and I'm really enjoying it so far. Like many beginners, I am following the donut series - haven't finished yet but I want some help with the icing. Right now my project looks like this (first pic), but I want it to have some imperfections, like in the second pic. I was thinking of maybe putting a texture or something. What are my possibilities?

I also noticed that the icing frequently has some small cracks. I searched about how to do it but couldn't understand much, so I guess I'll just forget about it for now.

Any help is appreciated, thanks! :)

[image: 1. What I've got so far][image: 2. texture and imperfections]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe first deform the topology a bit to make the shape less perfect, you can also use the *Sculpt* tools to do it.

To make procedural crackings you could use a *(Texture) Voronoi Texture* (*Distance* output, *3D* and *Distance to Edge* modes) that you plug into a *(Converter) ColorRamp* (with b&w needles pretty close to each other) that you plug into a *(Vector) Bump Map* that you plug into the *Normal* socket of the *Principled BSDF*. To make it a bit more natural, twist the coordinates a bit with a *Noise Texture*:

[image]

Also it would be better to mix your *Voronoi* with another *Noise* to give a bit of bumps to the surface, use a *Color > MixRGB* in *Multiply* mode:

[image]

Comment: It worked, thanks for the explanation! One question on the last suggestion though, which node do I use to mix the two textures?

Comment: @ClaraMortenson You may want to use just this shader, and not combine it with your current shader.

Comment: @Clara Mortenson: you can use a Color > MixRGB in Multiply mode, then play with the factor of this MixRGB